# Specify schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering what the best way to define this schema is:

[image]

Newsitem can only have 1 userID and 1 task ID. 
A Task can belong to many newsitems.
A user can belong to many newsitems

I've searched for examples, but I'd say they are not a lot of examples. How can I do this with mongoose & mongodb ? I'd say that both User to newsitem and Task to Newsitem are one to many relations.

Comment: Just a question, which software are you using to draw the diagram? looks very nice.

Comment: http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Comment: Your deleted implementation seems reasonable for me. in NewsItem you have a reference to the user, and to the task, than as @GabrielLlamas suggested populate when querying NewsItem.

Comment: Hey, did u solved ur problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mongodb you can reference a collection within a schema so when you find() a document in newsitem mongoose does a find() in user and task, so instead of returning the newsitem document it returns the newsitem with the user and the task.

[Mongoose population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)