# Mongoose: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I'm trying to specify the schema of my db in mongoose. At the moment I do this:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var today = new Date(2011, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0);


var personSchema = new Schema({  
   _id : Number,
   name: { type: String, required: true },  
   tel: { type: String, required: true },  
   email: { type: String, required: true },
   newsitems: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'NewsItem'}]
});

var taskSchema = new Schema({ 
    _id: Number,
    description: { type: String, required: true },  
    startDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    newsitems: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'NewsItem'}]
});

var newsSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    creator : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
    task : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Task' },
    date: { type: Date, required:true },
    loc: {type: String, required: true }  
});

var NewsItem  = mongoose.model('NewsItem', newsSchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
var Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);



var tony = new Person({_id:0, name: "Tony Stark", tel:"234234234", email:"tony@starkindustries.com" });
var firstTask = new Task({_id:0, description:"Get an interview with the president", startDate:today});
var newsItem1 = new NewsItem({_id:0, creator: tony.id, task: firstTask.id, date: today, loc: "NY"});

newsItem1.save(function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);

    firstTask.save(function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });

    tony.save(function (err) {
         if (err) console.log(err);
    }); 
});



NewsItem
.findOne({ loc: "NY" })
.populate('creator')
.populate('task')
.exec(function (err, newsitem) {
  if (err) console.log(err)
    console.log('The creator is %s', newsitem.creator.name);
})
```

I create the schemas and try to save some data.

The error:

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "0" at path "creator"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: '0',
  path: 'creator' }
```

I wrote this code based on : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#gsc.tab=0

The db I try to create looks like this: [Specify schema in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747130/specify-schema-in-mongoose) .

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The example from the mongoose docs you referenced uses `Number` for the `personSchema._id` field, and `ObjectId` for the others.

I presume they do this in the example only to demonstrate that it's possible to use either.  If you do not specify `_id` in the schema, `ObjectId` will be the default.

Here, all your records have an `_id` field which is an `ObjectId`, yet you're treating them like numbers.  Furthermore, fields like `personID` and `taskID` do not exist, unless you've left out the part where you define them.

If you did want to use numbers for all your `_id` fields, you'd have to define that in the schemas.

```
var newsSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  _creator: {type: ObjectId, ref: "Person"},
  // ...
})

var personSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  // ...
})
```

Then to create a news item with a particular ID, and assign it to a creator:

```
var tony = new Person({_id: 0});
var newsItem = new NewsItem({_id: 0, creator: tony.id});
```

However the thing to note here is that when you use something other than `ObjectId` as the `_id` field, you're taking on the responsibility of managing these values yourself.  ObjectIds are autogenerated and require no extra management.

Edit: I also noticed that you're storing refs on both sides of your associations.  This is totally valid and you may want to do it sometimes, but note that you'd have to take care of storing the references yourself in the `pre` hook.

Comment: thx for the help, though when querying and populating, I get an error. Do you happen to know what I did wrong ? (updated the question)

Comment: Did you save them?  It seems like it should work, unless it's loading a previous news item which was saved without a creator.

Comment: I added the save part to the question and the error which it triggers

Comment: Like I said in the answer, the `creator` ref needs to be of type `Number`, not `ObjectId`.  And yeah, your code above is incorrect.  The `findOne` query would need to be inside the callback to be able to retrieve those new records.  And also, if you're not dumping the db in between running this script, you're just loading the first one matching "NY" repeatedly anyway.

Comment: So I should save the task and person first and then the newsitem ?

Comment: You're determining the id before you even save, it doesn't matter the order you save them, but *none of those saves* are happening before your find query as `save` is asynchronous.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But you're saying that the creator ref needs to be of type Number, do you mean the id of the personSchema ( which is a number)? or the creator attribute in newsSchema which is a ObjectId in your solution too ?

Comment: The creator attribute.  A mongoose db ref needs to match the type of the _id it's referencing.

Comment: ok got it, if I check the value after it is saved I get the correct name. thx a lot ! :)

Answer (score 5):

I was receiving this error after creating a schema:
`CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “[object Object]” at path “_id”` 
Then modifying it and couldn't track it down. I deleted all the documents in the collection and I could add 1 object but not a second. I ended up deleting the collection in Mongo and that worked as Mongoose recreated the collection.

Comment: I was receiving a similar error from passport, I just re-created to make sure I got exact:  `Error: Unknown authentication strategy "[object Object]"` - this is due to using `jwt` the reference to the node package, and not `'jwt'` the string, e.g.  passport constructor: `passport.authenticate('jwt', {
 session: false,
});`