# How to populate if field is not empty string if empty no need to populate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have an app that has huge amount of data previously saved in mongoDB. Now I need to populate some information if **referencePeople** not empty string. In my app **referencePeople** is *string* type instead of mongoose *ObjectId* type.

I don't want to change my schema. Is there any way to check **referencePeople** is empty or not before populate. or if empty avoid to populate.

schema:

```
var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    customer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Customer'},
    referencePeople: String, // can be "" or "customer id"
   ......
});
```

Tried bellow code but got an exception ***Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id"***

```
exports.getOrders = function(req, res) {
    Order.find({})
        .populate('customer')
        .populate({path: 'referencePeople', model: 'customer'})
        .exec(function(error, orders) {
            if(error) {
                return res.status(400).send({msg: 'Error occurred while getting orders.', error: error});
            }
            return res.status(200).send(orders);
        });
};
```

Now I want to populate *referencePeople* if it is not empty string.
Can I check before populate *referencePeople* is empty or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: Cast to ObjectId failed for value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771470/mongoose-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value)

Comment: updated my question. I know got cast error when try to convert empty string to object. But my question is how can I handle if it is empty string. Possibly not duplicate question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use **match** clause of [population query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)

So, your code should be smth like this:

```
exports.getOrders = function(req, res) {
  Order.find({})
    .populate('customer')
    .populate({
       'path': 'referencePeople',
       'match': { 'referencePeople': {'$ne': ''} }
     })
    .exec(function(error, orders) {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(400).send({msg: 'Error occurred while getting orders.', error: error});
        }
        return res.status(200).send(orders);
    });
```

};

Comment: hi @aeryaguzov, 'match': { 'referencePeople': {'$ne': ''} }  can check in *order* collection or *customer* collection ? I need check in *order* collection. thanks

Comment: In customer collection. Then try to use proper ref in schema, ex. {referencePeople: {type: String, ref: 'Customer'}. Tell me if it works and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *Mongoose can’t handle multi-level population yet, and populated fields are not Documents. Nesting schemas is helpful but it’s an
>   incomplete solution. Design your schemas accordingly.*

You are trying to reference the 'referencePeople' object using the existing ObjectID in the 2<sup>nd</sup> populate call

Try this

```
exports.getOrders = function(req, res) {
Order.find({})
    .populate('customer')
    .exec(function(error, orders) {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(400).send({msg: 'Error occurred while getting orders.', error: error});
        }
        //Try changing the referencePeople here
        return res.status(200).send(orders);
    });
```

};

**REFERENCE**: [MongoDB](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/52299826008/the-mean-stack-mistakes-youre-probably-making)