# mongoose doesn't return the output with findById

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I m learning nodejs and mongodb altogether with [getting MEAN application](https://github.com/simonholmes/getting-MEAN)

my system specifications are

ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)
 node v 6.1.0
 npm v 3.8.6

"mongodb": "^2.1.18",
"mongoose": "^4.4.16",

So far I have created schema and add an entry in mongodb collection through terminal using `db.locations.save()` and get the generated document **_id** with `db.locations.find()`.

db.locations.find().pretty() in terminal returns below output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57428745e89f5c55e1d057dc"),
     // and many other path 
}
```

Now when I open **/api/locations/57428745e89f5c55e1d057dc** in browser, it neither gives result nor end the request. permanently show loading.. when testing with postman.

even tried with wrong Id than it returns proper error

> {"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value
>   \"57428745e89f5c55e1d057dca\" at path
>   \"_id\"","name":"CastError","kind":"ObjectId","value":"57428745e89f5c55e1d057dca","path":"_id"}

and with correct id

```
console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.locationid));  // return true
```

even tried

`findOne({"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.locationid) })`

But no results

What could be the issue? Is there any bug in mongoose or anything missing .Below are my basic files with required code

#### loc8r/app.js

```
require('./app_api/models/db');
var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');
app.use('/api', routesApi);
```

#### loc8r/app_api/models/db.js

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );    
var mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/loc8r';    
var mongoDB = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

mongoDB.on('connected', function (){
    console.log('mongoose connected to ' + mongoURI);
});

require('./locations');
```

---

#### loc8r/app_api/models/locations.js

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );    
var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
days: {type: String, required: true},
opening: String,
closing: String,
closed: {type: Boolean, required: true}
});

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
author: String,
rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
reviewText: String,
createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    address: String,
    rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
    facilities: [String],
    coords: {type: [Number], index: '2dspehere'},
    openingTime: [openingTimeSchema],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

#### loc8r/app_api/router/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations');

/* Locations pages */
router.get('/locations/:locationid', ctrlLocations.locationsReadOne);
```

---

#### loc8r/app_api/controllers/locations.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Loc = mongoose.model('Location');

module.exports.locationsReadOne =  function (req, res) {
    if(req.params && req.params.locationid) {            
        Loc
        .findById(req.params.locationid)
        .exec(function(err, location) {
            if(err) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
                return;
            }
            if (!location) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {"message": "locationid not found"});
                return;
            }
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, location);
        });
    } else {
         sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {"message": "no location id in request"});
    }
}

var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};
```

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771470/mongoose-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value

Comment: Sorry but that does not solve my problem. already search over google and mongoose github issues.

Comment: Did you try the other answer?

Comment: yes. I have created new document and tried too. not helped

Comment: Are you sure that `locationsReadOne` is getting reached at all? Are you using some kind of middleware in your app that may be causing the request to hang?

Comment: how do I find that? as i have set `console.log()` inside  **locationsReadOne** and it appears on console. is there anything else? I also suspect that something is blocking the request

Comment: If the `console.log()` appears you should be okay there. You can try the same for `sendJsonResponse()` but it looks to me like that should always be called as well.

Comment: Are you able to reach `module.exports.locationsReadOne` when you debug application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the solution from [mongoose documentation](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/README.md)

> **Important!** If you opened a separate connection using
>   mongoose.createConnection() but attempt to access the model through
>   mongoose.model('ModelName') it will not work as expected since it is
>   not hooked up to an active db connection. In this case access your
>   model through the connection you created:

so changing the way I create the connection

```
//var mongoDB = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);
mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
```

also need to comment all other functions/expression which use *mongoDB* variable

---

**Alternative approach :** ( if you do not want to change *mongoDB* in **db.js** )

in **controllers/locations.js**

change `var Loc = mongoose.model('Location');` with below line

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/loc8r');
var Loc = mongoose.model('Location');
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue, so I updated my Model file. For e.g.

```
const workoutsSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.ObjectId,
  email_add: String,
  workout_date: String,
  workout_duration: String
});
```

In the controller:-

```
  router.route("/workouts/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  console.log("Fetch Workouts of="+req.params.id);
  var id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  Workouts.findById(id, function(err, workout) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(workout);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** console your req.params before if

loc8r/app_api/controllers/locations.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Loc = mongoose.model('Location');

module.exports.locationsReadOne =  function (req, res) {
```

**console.log(req.params)**

```
    if(req.params && req.params.locationid) {            
        Loc
        .findById(req.params.locationid)
        .exec(function(err, location) {
            if(err) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
                return;
            }
            if (!location) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {"message": "locationid not found"});
                return;
            }
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, location);
        });
    } else {
         sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {"message": "no location id in request"});
    }
}

var sendJsonResponse = function(res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};
```

if params empty, or console not work, then check your route path

**or**

2. console something inside sendJsonResponse, maybe your function not work. Because if permanently show loading, it mean you dont send response.

**or**

3. Try to update mongodb to latest version, maybe mongoose work not correct with mongodb 2.1.18. It`s realy very old version.

Comment: `console.log(req.params)` outputs *{ locationid: '57428745e89f5c55e1d057dc' }*

Comment: also upgraded mongodb to 3.2.6 but still no difference

Comment: ever if I change last character of `locationid` , it doesn't throw any error

Comment: Try enother query to enother collection. Maybe problem with moongoose conection... Or try find with enother filed.

Comment: sorry but latest mongodb can't be installed on my ubuntu 16.04 / also tried with other collections as well but same issue. see my next problem [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656700/mongoose-does-not-create-document)

Answer (score 0):

try rewrite location controller like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Location = mongoose.model('Location');

exports.locationsReadOne = function (req, res) {
    if (req.params && req.params.locationid)
        Location.findById(req.params.locationid, function (err, location) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            if (location) return res.status(200).json(location);
            return res.status(404).json({"message": "locationid not found"})
        })
    else
        return res.status(200).json({"message": "no location id in request"})
}
```

Comment: you are using diffrent method with `res.status` , once `.send` and twice `.json`  ,why so?

Comment: i just modified code of person give this question. I think it's unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Hey try by converting your id to object id

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Location = mongoose.model('Location');

exports.locationsReadOne = function (req, res) {
if (req.params && req.params.locationid)
    Location.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.locationid), function (err, location) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        if (location) return res.status(200).json(location);
        return res.status(404).json({"message": "locationid not found"})
    })
else
    return res.status(200).json({"message": "no location id in request"})
}
```

Comment: do I need to include **models/locations** file in **controllers/locations** or current method is fine?

Comment: did you tried with other methods like find or findOne? Is it giving you the same error?

Comment: yes. I tried both `find` and `findOne` .. both request keep hanging

Comment: Did you console the result ? what are you getting?

Comment: nothing.request ended than 

`GET /api/locations/5742b0e3b7d7c67dc946d9f3 - - ms - -`

Comment: I mean on the backend terminal. So that we can identify where is the actual problem

Comment: yes. on the terminal it returns nothing . What is the means by `backend terminal` . where I run `nodemon` from the project folder . is that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `req.params.locationid` to `req.query.locationid` in the `findById()` method