# mongoose does not create document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using nodejs (6.2.1) and mongoose(4.4.16) with mongodb(2.1.21) on ubuntu 16.04 and create a signup form but when I submit mongoose does not create the doucment and request keep waiting. Kindly help me to solve the issue. below are the file structure

**views** are on app-server folder which are perfect so I am not including that structure

```
app-api
├── controllers
│   └── users.js
├── models
│   ├── db.js
│   └── users.js
└── routes
    └── index.js
```

#### routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlUsers = require('../controllers/users');

router.get('/user', ctrlUsers.userInfo);
router.post('/signup', ctrlUsers.userSignup);

module.exports = router;
```

#### models/db.js

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );
var mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/local';
var mongoDB = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

mongoDB.on('connected', function (){
    // console.log("enviorment:" + process.env.NODE_ENV);
    // console.log("mongolab:" + process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
    console.log('mongoose connected to ' + mongoURI);
});

mongoDB.on('disconnected', function (){
    console.log('mongoose disconnected ');
});

require('./users');
```

#### models/users.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    gender: {type: Boolean, "default": "m"},
    createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

#### controllers/users.js

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );
var User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports.userInfo = function(req,res) {
    res.render('signup', {
        title: 'User List'
    });
};

module.exports.userSignup = function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(User);
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        // console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
        User.create({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.email
        },function (err, user) {
            console.log(err);
            if(err) handleError(err);
            console.log('User saved successfully!');
        });
    }
};
```

here `console.log(req.body);` outputs whetever we send through form

`{ username: 'alpha', email: 'beta@gamma.com', password: 'delta' }`

and `console.log(User)` outputs

```
{ [Function: model]
  hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
  base: 
   Mongoose {
     connections: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     plugins: [],
     models: { User: [Circular], Location: [Object] },
     modelSchemas: { User: [Object], Location: [Object] },
     options: { pluralization: true } },
  modelName: 'User',
  model: [Function: model],
  db: 
   NativeConnection {
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     collections: { users: [Object], locations: [Object] },
     models: { User: [Circular], Location: [Object] },
     config: { autoIndex: true },
     replica: false,
     hosts: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     user: null,
     pass: null,
     name: null,
     options: null,
     otherDbs: [],
     _readyState: 0,
     _closeCalled: false,
     _hasOpened: false,
     _listening: false },
  discriminators: undefined,
  schema: 
   Schema {
     paths: 
      { username: [Object],
        password: [Object],
        email: [Object],
        gender: [Object],
        createdOn: [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        __v: [Object] },
     subpaths: {},
     virtuals: { id: [Object] },
     singleNestedPaths: {},
     nested: {},
     inherits: {},
     callQueue: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     _indexes: [],
     methods: {},
     statics: {},
     tree: 
      { username: [Object],
        password: [Object],
        email: [Object],
        gender: [Object],
        createdOn: [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        id: [Object],
        __v: [Function: Number] },
     _requiredpaths: undefined,
     discriminatorMapping: undefined,
     _indexedpaths: undefined,
     s: { hooks: [Object], queryHooks: [Object] },
     options: 
      { typeKey: 'type',
        id: true,
        noVirtualId: false,
        _id: true,
        noId: false,
        validateBeforeSave: true,
        read: null,
        shardKey: null,
        autoIndex: null,
        minimize: true,
        discriminatorKey: '__t',
        versionKey: '__v',
        capped: false,
        bufferCommands: true,
        strict: true,
        pluralization: true } },
  collection: 
   NativeCollection {
     collection: null,
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'users',
     collectionName: 'users',
     conn: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: null,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 0,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: false,
        _listening: false },
     queue: [ [Object] ],
     buffer: true,
     emitter: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined } } }
```

when I run `mongo` on terminal and try `use local` `show collections` doesn't give any output

Comment: what is this `models: { User: [Circular] ..}`

Comment: IMHO `local` is not replicable https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/local-database. In the sense that the database you are writing to is probably not the one you are referring to on terminal.

Comment: okay. I have created db `loc8r` and change it to `loc8r` and still same issue

Comment: What output are you getting ?

Comment: I have already pasted the output in Question

Comment: Dude I'm talking about the output when `show collections` lol

Comment: show collections not displaying anything, I think it will display when there would be atlease one document created

Comment: it's really frustrating when try to learn the basic and stuck on first step :( also there is no clear solutions on the web. someone using `module.exports  = mongoose.model(...)` in schema file while someone using `require(filename)` no clear difference at all

Comment: I've been through that, you'll get over it. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js. Okay so try one more thing, just uncomment the `console.log` in your code and see if the request was going ?

Comment: request is going my friend, that's why `console.log` output the data. I havn't commented `console.log`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got the solution from [`mongoose documentation`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/README.md)

> Important! If you opened a separate connection using
>   mongoose.createConnection() but attempt to access the model through
>   mongoose.model('ModelName') it will not work as expected since it is
>   not hooked up to an active db connection. In this case access your
>   model through the connection you created:

So now there are two approaches

**First:** Change the connection string in **db.js**

from

`var mongoDB = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);`

to

```
  mongoose.connect(mongoURI); 

  var mongoDB = mongoose.connection;
```

---

**Second:** Change the lines where using `.model()` in **controllers/users.js**

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );   
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/loc8r'); 
var User = conn.model('User');
```