# Mongoose save not working for some odd reason from a findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Gig.findOne({
  _id: data.gig
}).populate(populate).exec(function(err, gig) {
  gig.lastChatTime = Date.now();
  gig.lastChatBy = params.by;
  gig.meta.chats += 1;
  return gig.save(function(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

When I do the `.save`, it doesn't save, but it also doesn't error. What gives?

Comment: It would be great if you could include some sample documents or your schema design in order to replicate the same issue.

Comment: The model is huge - over 500 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
Gig.findOne({
  _id: data.gig
}).populate(populate).exec(function(err, gig) {
   if(gig){

      Gig.update({_id: gig._id},
                 {
                   lastChatTime : Date.now(),
                   lastChatBy : params.by,
                   meta.chats : meta.chats+ 1
                 },
                 {
                   runValidators: true
                 },function(err){
                 if(err){
                   throw err;
                 }
        );
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I get an error: `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "false" at path "salesEngineerGuess"`

Comment: without models it is difficult to say what the problem is. try to remove it:

                 {
                   runValidators: true
                 },

Comment: i think this post can help you now

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771470/mongoose-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value